# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object using re.findall()

Tags: python, html, regex, python-requests, python-re

I am beginning to solve programming CTFs in Python when I came accross a challenge for automating math calculations to get the flag.

The source code of the welcoming page looks like this:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FastMath</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content" style="text-align: center;">

Can you solve the level 1?<br/><h3><div id='calc'>1 + 1</div></h3><br/>
<form action="play.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="res" />
 <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

I wrote my Python code to automate it in order to get the flag as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import re
encoding = 'utf-8'
url = '0.0.0.0:8091'
session = requests.Session()

response = session.get(url)
content = response.text

while True:
    try:
        #solves = re.findall('Can you solve the level (.*) ?', content)[0]
        number =  re.findall('(?:[0-9 ()]+[*+/-])+[0-9 ()]+', content)[0]

        post_url = url + '/play.php'
        solution = eval(number)
        post_data = { "res" : solution }

        response = session.post(post_url, data = post_data)
        content = response.content

        #debug
        print(content)
        #print('number of solves: ' + solves)
    except:
        flag = re.findall('FLAG{(.*)}', content)[0]
        print(flag)
        break
```

It manages to make the first calculation as I get Can you solve the level 2? and submits as I can see from the output but then it gives out errors:

```
b'<html>\n\n<head>\n\n\t<meta charset="utf-8">\n\t<title>FastMath</title>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n\t<div id="content" style="text-align: center;">\n\t\tCan you solve the level 2?<br/><h3><div id=\'calc\'>1 - 5</div></h3><br/>\t\t<form action="#" method="post">\n\t\t\t<input type="text" name="res" /></p>\n\t\t\t<p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>\n\t\t</form>\n\t</div>\n</body>\n\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mmm.py", line 14, in <module>
    number =  re.findall('(?:[0-9 ()]+[*+/-])+[0-9 ()]+', content)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mmm.py", line 27, in <module>
    flag = re.findall('LMFRCTF{(.*)}', content)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I tried making in the converting it all to string but it didn't work, even using `r"something"` or `b"something"` didn't help much!

Comment: `re.findall` might not return the object you wanted.

Comment: Are there other alternatives to use in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.text` will give you a `str`, not `byte`s but `response.content` will give you `byte`s.

Choose the type you want to use and use it consistently.

`re` will handle bytes if the regular expression is `byte`s as well.